# Using css, keep button visibility hidden until sibling input expanded or contains text

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass

Got a search component in ReactJS I'm working on. Here's an example https://codepen.io/illusionfactory/pen/ZERwyxv

When the input field has focus, it expands and so does its parent container. The input has a sibling button.

With css (without JS), is it possible to only show the button when
a) the input field is expanded, or
b) input field has text? Otherwise the button is hidden?

Wondering if it can be done using css, without JS. I was attempting `:focus-within` on the container and `:last-child` but didn't have much luck.

Comment: If you are able to add a placeholder to the input you can achieve this: https://codepen.io/epsilon42/pen/rNKPGKM

Comment: you can use `<input type="search">` for searching input field it gives you **X** for delete inputs.